# join dataframe to nested tibbles

Tags: r

I have a nested tibble:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  period          data            
  <chr>           <list>          
1 Jy_2014_Je_2015 <tibble [7 x 7]>
2 Jy_2013_Je_2014 <tibble [3 x 7]>
```

Where one of the nests looks like:

```
> unnest(df1)
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   period          ID       CompYear  filing_date  mgnt  risk start_date end_date  
   <chr>           <chr>    <chr>     <date>      <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>    
 1 Jy_2014_Je_2015 71327810 2013_2014 2014-08-20  0.871 0.749 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 2 Jy_2014_Je_2015 56357140 2014_2015 2015-02-24  0.915 0.958 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 3 Jy_2014_Je_2015 71340910 2014_2015 2015-02-10  0.787 0.934 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 4 Jy_2014_Je_2015 09367110 2013_2014 2014-08-26  0.852 0.750 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 5 Jy_2014_Je_2015 G5785G10 2014_2015 2015-02-26  0.966 0.991 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 6 Jy_2014_Je_2015 20825150 2014_2015 2015-03-02  0.966 0.973 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 7 Jy_2014_Je_2015 55616P10 2014_2015 2015-02-23  0.991 0.920 2015-06-01 2016-05-30
 8 Jy_2013_Je_2014 08499Z00 2013_2014 2014-03-19  0.936 0.282 2014-06-01 2015-05-30
 9 Jy_2013_Je_2014 59268810 2013_2014 2014-02-21  0.952 0.911 2014-06-01 2015-05-30
10 Jy_2013_Je_2014 01858110 2013_2014 2014-01-31  0.953 0.966 2014-06-01 2015-05-30
```

The `df2` looks like:

```
> df2
           ID       date   Var1   date_ret
  1: 01858110 2012-01-31 110.80 2012-01-31
  2: 01858110 2012-02-29 121.36 2012-02-29
  3: 01858110 2012-03-30 125.96 2012-03-30
  4: 01858110 2012-04-30 128.49 2012-04-30
  5: 01858110 2012-05-31 126.00 2012-05-31
 ---                                      
231: G5785G10 2014-08-29  81.49 2014-08-29
232: G5785G10 2014-09-30  90.15 2014-09-30
233: G5785G10 2014-10-31  92.18 2014-10-31
234: G5785G10 2014-11-28  92.22 2014-11-28
235: G5785G10 2014-12-31  99.03 2014-12-31
```

I am trying to join `df2` and `df1` together. `df2` is a normal dataframe whereas `df1` is a nested tibble. They both contain `ID` variables I wish to join on and a `date` - `df2` contains monthly dates whereas `df1` contains yearly `dates`. Therefore I create a `start_date` and `end_date` to begin and end the joining dates. i.e. I want to join by the `ID` variable in both `df1` and `df2` and also the monthly data in `df2` to fit "between" the `start_date` and `end_date` in `df1`.

As far as I have got is to unnest the data I want and join them individually.

```
unnested_data <- unnest(df1)

myJoinedData <- setDT(df2)[, date_ret:=date][data.table(unnested_data), 
                                                      .(ID, date, Var1, 
                                                        period, filing_date, mgnt, start_date, end_date), 
                                                      on = .(ID, date > start_date, date <= end_date)]
```

Data:

```
    df1 <- structure(list(period = c("Jy_2014_Je_2015", "Jy_2013_Je_2014"
), data = list(structure(list(ID = c("71327810", "56357140", 
"71340910", "09367110", "G5785G10", "20825150", "55616P10"), 
    CompYear = c("2013_2014", "2014_2015", "2014_2015", "2013_2014", 
    "2014_2015", "2014_2015", "2014_2015"), filing_date = structure(c(16302, 
    16490, 16476, 16308, 16492, 16496, 16489), class = "Date"), 
    mgnt = c(0.871267898855628, 0.915166869000075, 0.786638982683625, 
    0.852085258472343, 0.965682470009356, 0.965813590885971, 
    0.990809585984218), risk = c(0.748733465269009, 0.958314403117101, 
    0.934083811166365, 0.749665010947671, 0.990592523426367, 
    0.973022180801192, 0.920155039512913), start_date = structure(c(16587, 
    16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587), class = "Date"), 
    end_date = structure(c(16951, 16951, 16951, 16951, 16951, 
    16951, 16951), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(ID = c("08499Z00", "59268810", 
"01858110"), CompYear = c("2013_2014", "2013_2014", "2013_2014"
), filing_date = structure(c(16148, 16122, 16101), class = "Date"), 
    mgnt = c(0.936233012426363, 0.951806853733034, 0.953036137199852
    ), risk = c(0.281925228286195, 0.911441002298349, 0.966068420793039
    ), start_date = structure(c(16222, 16222, 16222), class = "Date"), 
    end_date = structure(c(16585, 16585, 16585), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Data to join

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", 
"01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", 
"01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", 
"01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", 
"01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", 
"01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", "01858110", 
"01858110", "01858110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", 
"09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", 
"09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", 
"09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", 
"09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", 
"09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", "09367110", 
"09367110", "09367110", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", 
"55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", 
"55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", 
"55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", 
"55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", 
"55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", "55616P10", 
"55616P10", "55616P10", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", 
"56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", 
"56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", 
"56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", 
"56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", 
"56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", "56357140", 
"56357140", "56357140", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", 
"59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", 
"59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", 
"59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", 
"59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", 
"59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", "59268810", 
"59268810", "59268810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", 
"71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", 
"71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", 
"71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", 
"71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", 
"71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", "71327810", 
"71327810", "71327810", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", 
"G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", 
"G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10", 
"G5785G10", "G5785G10", "G5785G10"), date = structure(c(15370, 
15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 
15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 
15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 
16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 15370, 
15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 
15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 
15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 
16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 15370, 
15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 
15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 
15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 
16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 15370, 
15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 
15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 
15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 
16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 15370, 
15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 
15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 
15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 
16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 15370, 
15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 
15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 
15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 
16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 15884, 
15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 
16190, 16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 16343, 16374, 16402, 16435
), class = "Date"), Var1 = c(110.800003051758, 121.360000610352, 
125.959999084473, 128.490005493164, 126, 135, 130, 137.649993896484, 
141.949996948242, 143.050003051758, 142.490005493164, 144.759994506836, 
157.600006103516, 158.690002441406, 161.889999389648, 171.770004272461, 
177.089996337891, 181.029998779297, 197.779998779297, 195.699996948242, 
211.470001220703, 237.059997558594, 242.259994506836, 262.929992675781, 
239.660003662109, 285.109985351562, 272.450012207031, 241.899993896484, 
256.049987792969, 281.25, 262.290008544922, 264.640014648438, 
248.270004272461, 283.350006103516, 285.869995117188, 286.049987792969, 
16.3600006103516, 16.2999992370605, 16.4699993133545, 14.6999998092651, 
15.2700004577637, 15.9799995422363, 16.1299991607666, 16.5599994659424, 
17.3299999237061, 17.7000007629395, 18.0300006866455, 18.5699996948242, 
22.7700004577637, 24.8600006103516, 29.4200000762939, 27.7399997711182, 
29.2700004577637, 27.75, 31.4300003051758, 27.9099998474121, 
26.6599998474121, 28.4400005340576, 27.8899993896484, 29.0400009155273, 
30.3999996185303, 31.6399993896484, 30.1900005340576, 28.4200000762939, 
29.7800006866455, 33.5200004577637, 32.1300010681152, 33.5299987792969, 
31.0100002288818, 32.310001373291, 33.6399993896484, 33.6800003051758, 
33.689998626709, 37.9700012207031, 39.7299995422363, 41.0200004577637, 
38.0499992370605, 34.3499984741211, 35.8400001525879, 40.310001373291, 
37.6199989318848, 38.0699996948242, 38.7000007629395, 39.0200004577637, 
39.5099983215332, 41.0999984741211, 41.8400001525879, 44.5999984741211, 
48.3400001525879, 48, 48.3400001525879, 44.4300003051758, 43.2700004577637, 
46.1100006103516, 53.2599983215332, 53.4000015258789, 53.2000007629395, 
57.8600006103516, 59.2900009155273, 57.4300003051758, 59.8899993896484, 
58.0200004577637, 57.7900009155273, 62.2900009155273, 58.1800003051758, 
57.8199996948242, 64.9100036621094, 65.75, 13.4399995803833, 
15.7399997711182, 13.8599996566772, 13.8500003814697, 10.3999996185303, 
11.6999998092651, 12, 12.8800001144409, 13.3400001525879, 14.25, 
15, 15.6800003051758, 17.6000003814697, 18.5200004577637, 20.5599994659424, 
18.7600002288818, 21.0100002288818, 17.9099998474121, 20.5300006866455, 
19.9799995422363, 19.5610008239746, 19.4599990844727, 20.5900001525879, 
23.3199996948242, 28.4500007629395, 30.9400005340576, 31.4500007629395, 
31.7800006866455, 27.0499992370605, 32.8600006103516, 26.5599994659424, 
29.4200000762939, 23.4500007629395, 20.8400001525879, 20.1399993896484, 
22.1000003814697, 175.5, 180.279998779297, 184.75, 179.320007324219, 
156.119995117188, 155.850006103516, 154.800003051758, 165.110000610352, 
170.740005493164, 169.369995117188, 187.089996337891, 193.300003051758, 
212.529998779297, 212.800003051758, 213.220001220703, 208.960006713867, 
218.259994506836, 201.199996948242, 220.600006103516, 220.229995727539, 
240.089996337891, 247.460006713867, 246.570007324219, 242.589996337891, 
246.300003051758, 245.759994506836, 235.679992675781, 233.119995117188, 
245.020004272461, 253.179992675781, 257.140014648438, 270.480010986328, 
256.130004882812, 258.470001220703, 293.260009765625, 302.459991455078, 
15, 15.039999961853, 14.9200000762939, 14.9300003051758, 9.27999973297119, 
9.89999961853027, 9.06999969482422, 8.98999977111816, 10.1800003051758, 
9.98999977111816, 10.5699996948242, 9.82999992370605, 11.1300001144409, 
11.1300001144409, 11.789999961853, 11.6000003814697, 12.3400001525879, 
11.5799999237061, 12.4499998092651, 11.2299995422363, 12.4700002670288, 
12.9399995803833, 13.6999998092651, 12.1400003433228, 11.9399995803833, 
12.5900001525879, 12.7200002670288, 10.2200002670288, 10.1899995803833, 
11.460000038147, 10.5799999237061, 11.1199998855591, 8.90999984741211, 
9.52999973297119, 9.73999977111816, 9.81999969482422, NA, 45.8899993896484, 
43.6500015258789, 44.0900001525879, 42.0099983215332, 51.9599990844727, 
52.2599983215332, 57.8300018310547, 67.6900024414062, 63.4099998474121, 
71.2300033569336, 77.7600021362305, 80.0199966430664, 69.620002746582, 
81.4899978637695, 90.1500015258789, 92.1800003051758, 92.2200012207031, 
99.0299987792969)), row.names = c(NA, -235L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop through the `list` column with `map` and do the join

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ 
       as.data.table(df2)[, date_ret := date][data.table(.x),
     .(ID, date, Var1, filing_date, mgnt, start_date, end_date),
       on = .(ID, date > start_date, date <= end_date)]))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  period          data             
#  <chr>           <list>           
#1 Jy_2014_Je_2015 <df[,7] [7 × 7]> 
#2 Jy_2013_Je_2014 <df[,7] [15 × 7]>
```